# how to alter a string with NSRegularExpression

Tags: objective-c, nsregularexpression, nsmutablestring

I am a beginner in objective-c.

I have the following `NSMutableString stringVal=@"[abc][test][end]";`

What is the best way I should use in order to **REMOVE THE LAST [] piece (e.g [end])**?

I have this code:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\[]" options:0 error:NULL];
    NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:stringVal options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [stringVal length])];
    for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
        ?? what should i do here?
    }
```

Comment: Ok what i understand is you want to remove string end and then you wanted to add on your array right??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use this regular expression pattern `"\\[.*?]"` then you get three matches

```
['[abc]', '[test]', '[end]']
```

then can just get the range of the third match (check that you have at least three)

```
NSMutableString* stringVal= [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"[abc][test][end]"];
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\[.*?]" options:0 error:NULL];
NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:stringVal options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [stringVal length])];
NSTextCheckingResult* match = matches[2];

NSMutableString* substring = [[stringVal substringToIndex:match.range.location] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: I have the following working: Unknown escape sequence ""\"]". Also stringVal is a NSMutableString. How should i write if I want substring to be NSMutableString too?

Comment: it s not working . it doesn t display any [match rangeAtIndex:0]

Comment: NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\[.*?]" options:0 error:NULL];
    NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:stringval options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [stringval length])];
    NSTextCheckingResult *match = [matches lastObject];
    NSRange matchRange = [match range];
    NSLog(@"match is: %@",[stringval substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:0]]);

Comment: finally got xcode out, didn't realise you needed to escape the string and the re, so two back slashes before the [. Changed the answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

[jbat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/964813/jbat100) was right that you should modify the regex. After that, all you need is the last match, so you could use

```
NSTextCheckingResult *match = [matches lastObject]; // Get the last match
NSRange matchRange = [match range]; // Get the position of the match segment
NSString *result = [stringVal stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:matchRange  withString:@""]; // Replace the segment by an empty string.
```

Comment: Yes, I've just added your suggestion. Thanks.